# split on newlines AND commas AND semi-colons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to take a textarea's worth of people's names, entered by a user, and separate them into items in an array.

Take a theoretically possible input:

```
people = "Abby Andrews, Ben \r\nCharlie Connors    Daphne D., Ernie E. Engels; Faye\r\n\r\nGary Gomez"

array = people.split('??')
```

How can the regex be constructed to successfully split a crazy chain like the above?

Should be split:

- `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`
- comma (`,`) or semi-colon (`;`)
- multiple spaces

Should not be split:

- period (this could be someone's initial)
- single space (could be separating first and last names)

I tried `people.split(/\r\n,;/)`, `people.split(/,;\r\n/)`, and combinations thereof but none produced the result.

Comment: **What did you try so far?** There is a pretty obvious answer... and this is not a "please write my program for me" web site...

Comment: It might be a pretty obvious answer if you know how to do it. I tried `people.split(/\r\n,;/)`, `people.split(/,;\r\n/)`, and combinations thereof but none produced the result.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: It's not that trivial. For example, if you look at my answer, the order of the alternation is essential - if you were to swap around the three parts, the regex would malfunction. So I think a downvote is a bit harsh, especially now that sscirrus has commented to show her/his efforts. I'll put that into the question so it counts as a new edit, otherwise the downvotes would stick.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thank you Tim. I didn't know that the order of the alternation is essential in regexes - something else I've learned today!

Comment: @sscirrus: you really should look at a basic regexp tutorial. `/,;\r\n/' by definition is an *exact sequence* match. There are constructs in regular expressions to make *alternate* matches, which is what you need here. **Seriously, have a look at the tutorials. You will learn plenty.**

Comment: @TimPietzcker: the order of the alternation *should* be insignificant. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: For example `Item1,  (two spaces) Item 2 \r\n  (two spaces) Item3`. With another order, you would get empty splits. (imagine two spaces where I wrote `(two spaces)`; unfortunately the SO engine collapses multiple spaces in comments even if marked as verbatim text.)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference for me (tested in python, though). Plus, I'd make the whitespace handling explicit, as in my comment to your answer.

Comment: No. Tutorials cover basic stuff, such as character sets and alternate options in regexps (which even will be chapter 1, basic features). There are plenty of questions that are not covered by tutorials and that go beyond trial-and-error (unless you count the million monkeys approach as trial-and-error, that is). But yes, many people here could have had a look at the documentation first (it's actually even faster than waiting for a "custom tutorial").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
array = people.split(
    /\s*[,;]\s* # comma or semicolon, optionally surrounded by whitespace
    |           # or
    \s{2,}      # two or more whitespace characters
    |           # or
    [\r\n]+     # any number of newline characters
    /x)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the components mean Tim, very helpful! :)

Comment: I'd *not* leave away the parentheses. And I'd on the other hand always include excess whitespace in the separator pattern, i.e. `/\s*([,;\r\n]+|\s\s)\s*/`

Comment: what is the `x` in the modifier position?

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch It's the `VERBOSE` modifier that allows multiline, commented regexes.

Comment: ha. I used a modification of this regex for a javascript function. Suddenly I'm jealous of Ruby!

Comment: I tried with  data["hourly_budget"].split(/\s*([,;\r\n]+|\s\s)\s*/) but its not working

Comment: @Jaswinder: That's a completely different regex. If you need help with that, (there are several problems with it), you need to ask a new question. Comments are unsuitable for this.